# when I try to print a message, it prints a random symbol in place of the spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I'm writing a code that encrypts a message entered by the user in python. I shift the message by a number that the user inputs. However, when I print it, the spaces are replaced by random symbols.

```
print("""Welcome to the Encryption 'machine'""")
message=input('Please enter a message you wish to be encrypted ')
shift_num=int(input('Please enter the number that you wish to shift your message by'))

for value in message:
    value=ord(value)
    value=value+shift_num
    value=chr(value)
    value=value.replace(' ', '')
    print(value, end='')
```

This is what happens:

```
Welcome to the Encryption 'machine'
Please enter a message you wish to be encrypted: aaa bbb
Please enter the number that you wish to shift your message by: 2
ccc"ddd
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because space is a character too, which, when shifted a few places, will result in a different character. You would have to exclude spaces if you want to leave word boundaries intact. Perhaps you'd also want to keep punctuation marks.